# Reading hebrew in python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, hebrew

I have a conversation log in Hebrew (.txt). I opened the file, using        `f=open("./WhatsApp.txt",'r',encoding="cp037")`. In the file, each line of text consisted a date and a text (for example: 14/01/13 12:10:52: דני נרדפייטרס: איילת יא רעה). I defined `a=f.readlines()`, and here's the problem:

`>>> a[0]
'Õ]×\x91\x94\x07\x90\x91\x07\x91\x93\x80\x91\x16\x9a\x91\x90\x9a\x91\x04\x9a\x80SØ¡\x8b\x99\x04\x16\x80\x95\x90\x05\x16\x96\x94\x05\x91\x90\x98\x04SØÐ\x9a\x80PmPsPrPxPy\x80PzPmPjPpPrPyPnP¡\x80PmPrPn\x80PlPÆPnPxPyPqPrPnP¡\x80PnPæP°\x80PÆPzPnPpPlPnP¡\n'`

I tried to decode this (I want to have the dates and getting them from this string is hard), I did `codecs.decode(a[0],"cp037")`, and I got

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    codecs.decode(a[0],"cp037")
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp037.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`
```

Why is this happening? How can I read the file in a way that I could seperate each line to date and text?

Comment: @Xaranke: No they wouldn't as that's not the problem. He also clearly tells you what he have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You have opened the file in text mode, with an encoding, so it's already decoded. You don't need to decode it again.

Now that text doesn't look like it's correctly decoded, indicating that perhaps the text isn't in cp037 in the first place. Try opening it binary mode, and tell us what the file looks like then.

(In fact, I tried with UTF-8, and that worked. The file is in UTF-8, so just change cp037 to 'UTF-8' and it will work).

Comment: @user2334608: You don't need to say thank you on this site. Just upvote and select as answer. :-)